NX ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir ''
I use an NX monorepo, and I would like to build my frontend app. I get the following error:
 NX   ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir ''. I found some similar questions, but mine differs, as the scandir '' refers to no lib (quote marks are empty). I assume, the application's project.json should be configured properly. Here is the build block:
"build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/NQO/frontend",
        "index": "apps/NQO/frontend/src/index.html",
        "main": "apps/NQO/frontend/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js", "apps/NQO/frontend/src/polyfills.ts"],
        "tsConfig": "apps/NQO/frontend/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "apps/NQO/frontend/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/NQO/frontend/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "apps/NQO/frontend/src/styles.scss",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/material-icons-font/material-icons-font.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "outputPath": "dist/apps/NQO/frontend/prod",
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/NQO/frontend/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/NQO/frontend/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "aot": true,
          "optimization": true,
          "sourceMap": false,
          "commonChunk": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "15mB"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "450kb",
              "maximumError": "15mB"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },

,though I copied every parameter from a properly working workspace. Or the issue is completely unrelated to the project.json file? I gladly accept any help!

I'm using Angular v17.3.0, @nx v18.2.4 and node v20.12.1.
I tried the basic ways of fixing it (npm i, npm update, etc), none of them helped.

As of 2024 06 01, I am getting the same error out of the blue. Not sure what change I made that triggered the problem.

Could be related to the recent issue https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/26271 ?
